# Storing user-submitted files (images, pdfs) in a scalable way?

Tags: mongodb, file-upload, nginx, redis, storage

On my platform I am allowing users to upload their own images and pdfs.

In my IaaS VM I use nginx, Redis and MongoDB; so I was thinking maybe to store them temporarily in Redis then push them to a static file route in nginx. I need security permissions on the files (user access restrictions); so was thinking to store {filename↔access-control} information in MongoDB.

Is that the best approach; or is there a better one you can think of?

Comment: [Beaver, Doug, Sanjeev Kumar, Harry C. Li, Jason Sobel, Peter Vajgel, and Facebook Inc. “Finding a Needle in Haystack: Facebook’s Photo Storage.” In In Proc. of OSDI, 2010.](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Beaver.pdf) describes Facebook's scalable image storage approach. Not sure if I am prepared to deploy that level of distribution+scalability at this stage…

Comment: Any kind of datastore with automatic sharding and which can stream binary blobs will do the trick.

What's probably easiest is to upload it to a service for which you can generate expiring URLs to objects directly from the service. Eg. upload to amazon S3, then when a user requests a file, check permissions (however you want to do that) then generate a temporary URL to the file and redirect them to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I am going with:

- Pathname↔filename stored in database
- Metadata associated with filename (in the file name); providing namespacing (e.g.: for subsequent sharding between servers and data centres)
- Actual file stored on an nginx static file route (need to investigate security concerns here)

Still in need of suggestions on securing files from nginx without serving static files through e.g.: Python